# Document directory is good to store data or cache in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Friends i need to store more than 100 mb data which come in zip format and i get data after unzip this zip file and **unzip data is more than 70 mb** in size , **so my question is that which storage location is good to keep this data, currently i am using cache but it gives memory warning on device  when i writes data in cache** and then after sometimes app gets crashed.

This zip file contain html pages and images.

i checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679918/best-way-to-store-and-load-large-amount-of-data-in-objective-c) also but did't get answer to store thes html and images which comes in zip format from server.

Any small help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to read this entire ZIP file into memory at once! It's not the permanent storage (Flash) on the device which goves you the memory warning, but you eat up the RAM. Yes, the Documents or Library directory is fine for storing your app data, just be careful with the memory management.

Comment: thank u H2Co3 can u tell me how to save this zip file in document directory so that it could' t be sync with icloud.

Comment: So that it could NOT synced? That's the case for which I suggest the Library directory instead.

Comment: H2CO3 my one of my html path is -->iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/253AC820-4AFD-4237-91B3-44219DE02A36/Library/Caches/phone/1/1/article1.html, is this the right location to store data?

Answer (score 2):

Like H2CO3 stated, the memory warning is indeed caused by reading it all into RAM in one chunk. Apart from that, be sure to follow [Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/) regarding data storage. If the data being saved is temporary, be sure not to store it in your documents directory, otherwise your application might get rejected (Speaking from experience).

Comment: starvash my one of my html path is -->iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/253AC820-4AFD-4237-91B3-44219DE02A36/Library/Caches/phone/1/1/article1.html, is this the right location to store data?

Comment: Cache directory on the mac is mapped to a different relative path than it would have on the device. If you obtained a reference to the cache directory in a generic manner, I guess you're in the right direction.

Comment: This thread could also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209406/ios-5-does-not-allow-to-store-downloaded-data-in-documents-directory